# Does .Net Use Different Regex Engine?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am trying to capture 3 different strings from using Regular Expression:

```
Del Mar, CA, 92014
```

The outcome should be 3 separate captured strings:

- Del Mar
- CA
- 92014

Below regex works in regexlib.com, the output captures those 3 strings. But this does not work in C# .Net. .Net finds the matches, but doesn't capture 3 different strings

```
([a-zA-Z\s]*),*\s*([a-zA-Z]{2}),*\s*([0-9]{5,10})\s*
```

I tried different RegexOptions (IgnoreCase, ExplicitCapture, IgnorePatternWhitespace), all of them have same result (found matches but doesn't capture).

C# code:

```
var _regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"([a-zA-Z\s]*),*\s*([a-zA-Z]{2}),*\s*([0-9]{5,10})\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var _matches = _regex.Matches("Del Mar, CA, 92014");

return _matches.Cast<Match>()
   .Select(m => m.Value)
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: did you escaped the \ when using it in C#? Can we see your C# Code?

Comment: Can you show a short but complete program that demonstrates what you tried? I tried it, it seems to work according to your requirements so there may be something else wrong with your code.

Comment: Can you show your code that reads the match and gets the text for each group?

Comment: If your regex string is declared similar to this: string strRegex = @"([a-zA-Z\s]*),*\s*([a-zA-Z]{2}),*\s*([0-9]{5,10})\s*" + "\n";

It should work.

Comment: The `ExplicitCapture` option prevents the Regular Expression engine from treating `(` and `)` as a capture. If you do *not* include that flag, then the result will include 3 captures.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand the problem with program code when the code is absent. Please, provide [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will describe your problem more precisely and reduce any further speculations about actual details. And even more - creating clean and short problem demo will improve your own understanding of both the issue and the whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, the problem is in my own code. Mark was right. In this specific regex, the capture is 'stored' in `Match`

I ended up writing two helpers to extract values out of a regex, one for `Match` and one from `Group`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetMatches(string input, string regexPattern)
{
    var _regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var _matches = _regex.Matches(input);

    return _matches.Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToArray();
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetGroups(string input, string regexPattern)
{
    var _regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var _matches = _regex.Matches(input);

    return (from Match _m in _matches
            from Group _g in _m.Groups
            where _g.Value != _m.Value
            select _g.Value)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

`Match`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetUSPhone(string input)
{
    return GetMatches(input, @"([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})");
}
```

`Group`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetUSCityStateZip(string input)
{
    return GetGroups(input, @"(?<City>[a-zA-Z\x20]*)[,]*\t*\x20*(?<State>[a-zA-Z]{2})\x2C*\t*\s*(?<ZipCode>[0-9\x2D\x20]{5,10}|\x20*)");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just works fine for me,

```
String input = @"Del Mar, CA, 92014";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z\s]*),*\s*([a-zA-Z]{2}),*\s*([0-9]{5,10})\s*");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/IBZzVf)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't your regex, but how you are interpreting the results.  You will get back one `Match` with 4 `Group`s - the first will be the whole string, and the others will be the substrings you are capturing.  So, your return statement could be something like this:

```
return _matches[0].Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1)
    .Select(g => g.Value)
    .ToArray();
```